# C Programming : Need to get output of the number of letters in a string. (Newbie)

Tags: c, count, character, strcat

I am trying to complete an assignment, part of the assignment is to print the output of the number of letters in a string.

I was trying to reverse engineer the code that the instructor gave us, but his code is not even working. Or am I doing something wrong or missing something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[13] = "Hello"; 
    char str2[13] = "World";

    /* concatenates str1 and str2 */
    strcat(str1, str2);
    printf("strcat(str1, str2): %s\n", str1);

    /* total lenghth of str1 after concatenation */
    len = strlen(str1); 
    printf("strlen(str1) : %d\n", len); 
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I am getting is:

test2.c:13:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'len'
    len = strlen(str1); 
    ^
test2.c:14:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'len'
    printf("strlen(str1) : %d\n", len);

If I am not using the right identifier, how do I know which identifier covers the specific commands?

I will also be incorporating the following code in my assignment, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
char first[10] = "first";
char last[10] = "last";
char  full[20] = " ";

strcat(full, first);
strcat(full, " ");
strcat(full, last);
```

Ultimately I need to print the name (first, last, and full name), and then print the number of characters of each.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Try `int len = strlen(str1);`

Comment: How is it you know that you have to declare `char str1` and `char str2`, but don't know you have to declare `int len` also if you're going to use it? You find the type of identifier needed by reading the documentation for the function itself. `strlen`'s documentation tells you what type it returns, and the variable used to store that return value needs to be of that type.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
len = strlen(str1); 
printf("strlen(str1) : %d\n", len);
```

the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not a `int` and you need to declare the 'type' for every variable:

therefore:

```
size_t len = strlen(str1); 
printf("strlen(str1) : %d\n", len);
```

But the proper way to output a `size_t` is with the format specifier `%zu`  not: `%d`

Therefore:

```
size_t len = strlen(str1); 
printf("strlen(str1) : %zu\n", len);
```

regarding:

```
char  full[20] = " ";
strcat(full, first);
```

The array `full[]` is being set to contain a space in the first byte.  Using `strcat()` will keep that space, which you probably don't want.  Suggest:

```
char  full[20] = {'\0'};
strcat(full, first);
strcat(full, " ");
strcat(full, last);
```

or, not so good, because it results in a waste of a string containing nothing but a space and a NUL byte

```
char  full[20] = " ";
strcpy(full, first);
strcat(full, " ");
strcat(full, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have not declared any data type for len and that is why you are getting the error. First declare you are desired data type , in this case you can check the documentation of strlen function. So try declaring the data type of len first, the return data type for strlen function is mainly size_t but you can use it as int for basic use. Here if you are not aware of data types and do not need to store the value you can alternately also use

```
printf("strlen(str1) : %d\n", strlen(str1));
```